# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: breeze.linalg.tile$.tile_DM_Impl2

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-ml, scala-breeze

I have a spark code that use breeze. I can se the breeze version of my project:

```
$ gradle dependencies | grep breeze
     |    |    +--- org.scalanlp:breeze_2.11:0.12
     |    |    |    +--- org.scalanlp:breeze-macros_2.11:0.12
     +--- org.scalanlp:breeze_2.11:0.12 (*)
     |    |    +--- org.scalanlp:breeze_2.11:0.12
     |    |    |    +--- org.scalanlp:breeze-macros_2.11:0.12
     +--- org.scalanlp:breeze_2.11:0.12 (*)
     |    |    +--- org.scalanlp:breeze_2.11:0.12
     |    |    |    +--- org.scalanlp:breeze-macros_2.11:0.12
     +--- org.scalanlp:breeze_2.11:0.12 (*)
|    |    |    +--- org.scalanlp:breeze_2.11:0.12
|    |    |    |    +--- org.scalanlp:breeze-macros_2.11:0.12
|    +--- org.scalanlp:breeze_2.11:0.12 (*)
|    |    |    +--- org.scalanlp:breeze_2.11:0.12
|    |    |    |    +--- org.scalanlp:breeze-macros_2.11:0.12
|    +--- org.scalanlp:breeze_2.11:0.12 (*)
```

The version of breeze included in spark 2.1.1 is 0.12. I can see this looking in the spark jars directory:

```
spark-2.1.1-bin-hadoop2.4$ find . -name *.jar | grep breeze
./jars/breeze_2.11-0.12.jar
./jars/breeze-macros_2.11-0.12.jar
```

But when I submit the job to spark (even local) I get this error:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: breeze.linalg.tile$.tile_DM_Impl2(Lscala/reflect/ClassTag;Lbreeze/storage/Zero;Lbreeze/generic/UFunc$InPlaceImpl2;)Lbreeze/generic/UFunc$UImpl2;
    at mypackage.MyClass.calcOne(MyClass.scala:51)
    at mypackage.MyClass$$anonfun$1.apply(MyClass.scala:36)
    at mypackage.MyClass$$anonfun$1.apply(MyClass.scala:35)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:409)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:893)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1336)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.foldLeft(TraversableOnce.scala:157)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foldLeft(Iterator.scala:1336)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.fold(TraversableOnce.scala:212)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.fold(Iterator.scala:1336)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$fold$1$$anonfun$20.apply(RDD.scala:1044)
```

The command line used:

```
spark-2.1.1-bin-hadoop2.4/bin/spark-submit --class my.Main myjar.jar
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem:

My **SPARK_HOME** environment variable was setting to an old spark version.

So **bin/spark-class** was looking for jars dependencies in this other path